# SQL "find missing index" script suggests missing index that already exists? Query in top 10 CPU list

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-execution-plan

One query is in the top of the most cpu intensive list, but it's simplicity (see example below) contradicts this. However the "find missing index" script suggests creating an index for the table... but this exact (column order and include) index already exists.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) 
  FROM dbo.ProductOrder
 WHERE userId = @userId
   AND status = @status
```

The "find missing index" script suggest an index on userId and status.

We noticed the missing index suggest a couple of weeks ago and found a post (somewhere) that this would be a bug in SQL Server R2 SP1 (the version we use).

But now the query is (and stays) in the top 10... I'm not sure anymore.

Things we tried:

- Adding the Id to the include list (not suggested)
- NOLOCK / READ UNCOMMITED transaction isolation level
- sp_recompile on the table

We have a tight maintenance schedule ensuring fragmentation is kept to a minimum.

What could be happing here?

Edit: I mentioned execution plan when I started the post, but the execution plans don't actually mention the index (anymore). The "find missing index" script does.

Edit 2: Index definition

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ProductOrder_UserStatus_Nidx] ON [dbo].[ProductOrder]
(
    [userId] ASC,
    [status] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Edit 3: Missing Index output

```
statement: dbo.ProductOrder
improvement_measure: 187243,941382055
create_index_statement: CREATE INDEX [missing_index_4_3_ProductOrder] ON [dbo].[ProductOrder] ([userId], [status])
group_handle: 4
unique_compiles: 10
user_seeks: 51161
user_scans: 0
last_user_seek: 2014-06-22 10:06:12.390
last_user_scan: NULL
avg_total_user_cost: 8,77252167199463
avg_user_impact: 41,72
system_seeks: 0
system_scans: 0
last_system_seek: NULL
last_system_scan: NULL
avg_total_system_cost: 0
avg_system_impact: 0
database_id: 8
object_id: 2014122416
```

**Update: New script found right query**

We we're looking at the wrong query. A new script found the one that actually produces the missing index statement in the query plan:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductOrder_GetByUserAndStatus]
  @userId INT, 
  @status INT,
  @deliveryStatus INT
AS

 SELECT U.id
      , U.email
      , U.[language]
      , U.username
      , U.firstname + ' ' + ISNULL(u.middlename, '') + ' ' + u.lastname AS fullname
      , pp.[product]
      , pp.[status]
      , pp.[deliveryStatus]
   FROM [dbo].[ProductOrder] PO
   JOIN [dbo].[User] U ON U.[id] = PO.[userId] 
    AND PO.[pool] = @userId 
      AND PO.[status] = @status
    AND PO.[deliveryStatus] = ISNULL(@deliveryStatus, PO.[deliveryStatus])

RETURN 0
```

Maybe SQL server is lost because of the last line in the where clause that implements the optional filter parameter?

I've tried creating updating the index to include the deliveryStatus in the column list as well as the INCLUDE statement (in two seperate updates, running statistics an recompile); the first solution got a performance degradation (missing index remained in plan) and the second showed no difference.

Close this issue as a bug in SQL server?

Comment: It happens.......Sometimes it suggests duplicate indexes. That's why you shouldn't blindly follow its suggestions....Are your stats up to date?

Comment: If you're 100% sure the index is good, you can use index hints to force SQL Server to use that index.

Comment: Use forced index hints as an absolute last resort.

Comment: So what does the execution plan look like? It isn't seeking into the index on those two columns?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem with the current execution plan? Just because it's in the "top 10" doesn't mean it's a bad plan. You could simply be calling it a million times an hour.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I didn't know these hints existed. I've added them, let's see what happens. Query Plan stopped suggesting the Index.

Comment: I'm wondering if the `NULL`ness of `Id` makes a difference. If you have a non-clustered index on `(userId, status)` then that index would be an excellent candidate for `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE userId ... status ...`.

Comment: I've made the COUNT(*) adjustment. The SP has been called 7 million times pas 4 days.

Comment: The find missing index script may be recommending the index for a different query than the one you have shown us. IIRC the missing index DMVs just note missing indexes and don't tell you affected plans. Are you sure the order of the key columns isn't reversed in the suggestion vs the index you have?

Comment: Why are you leaving us in the dark about the index definition and the plan. Start providing this information. Until we have it it is not worth investing more time here.

Comment: Ok, the index is basically perfect. If the plan does not use it there is some problem which is not visible with the given information. Post the plan as XML somewhere. Maybe on pastebin.

Comment: And please post the actual output of the missing index DMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what indexes are there? Hopefully one on `userId, status INCLUDE (Id)`. Nothing else is required (and any additional column will slow down this query). If `Id` is not null or part of the CI anyway you don't even need to include it. Probably, you meant and should write `COUNT(*)` anyway because you probably don't care to not count nulls in `Id`.

If you want to optimize this to a single-row lookup by a clustered index (which is incredibly fast) use an indexed view that groups by `userId, status`.

Locking, contrary to common superstition, is not a likely suspect here. In fact, `NOLOCK` is quite dangerous.

Comment: The include of Id was not there. We tried adding the Id but the missing index kept showing (without the Id or any include whatsoever). I changed the count to *. I'll also have look at the indexed view as a solution.

Comment: The missing index message is just a bug. Or not. If you post your index definition we can make sure. If there are just a lot of rows to count or the query runs very often, there's nothing you can do with a simple index.

Comment: I've added the index def. 780K rows exist in the table.